# How to create a popup like Stripe checkout

Tags: php, python, angularjs, ruby, stripe-payments

I have been tasked with creating a web application that creates popups on other sites like Stripe checkout does those using this code (attached below) in checkout documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart). I have experience with Iframe but not using script tags.

Any advice or sample code will do.

```
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">   
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
          class="stripe-button"     
          data-key="pk_test_g6do5S237ekq10r65BnxO6S0"     
          data-amount="999"     
          data-name="Stripe.com"    
          data-description="Example charge"     
          data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"     
          data-locale="auto"    
          data-zip-code="true">  
  </script> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are loading is basically javascript. Here is the script you are loading: https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js.

This script creates the pop up called a "Modal".

Here is a tutorial from W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

This should be enough to get you started.